# Removing a large space from a text in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to remove a big whitespace and retain the CR and LF character in a String. This string is generated by Lotus Domino API. This is basically an eml file converted to text by Lotus API.

When I do the below :

```
String input = "This is a      test string\r\nThis is another       test string";
String tmp = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.println(tmp);


Output: 
This is a test string This is another test string

Desired Output : 
This is a test string\r\nThis is another test string
```

Removing whitespace is not an issue but I am not able to retain the carriage return and linefeed in the String. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answers from Tuga and Lance Java also fix this issue. But the answer from @Casimir et Hippolyte suits my need best, hence marking that as accepted answer. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple trick, replace `\\s` with a negated character class :`[^\\S\\r\\n]` where `\\S` is "all that is not a white character".

Note: if you want to preserve a space between words, you must change your replacement string to `" "`

Example:

```
String tmp = input.replaceAll("[^\\S\\r\\n]+", " ");
```

Note: You can use a class intersection too: `[\\s&&[^\\r\\n]]`

Comment: `[^\\S\\r\\n]+` might be even better.

Comment: @Dropout: I said: replace `\\s` not `\\s+`

Comment: LOL, using a pseudo-regex in a question about regexes. Now that's hard core. I take it back, you're technically right.

Comment: When I replaced with the negated char class given by you, the spaces between the words also vanished as below:
`Thisisateststring
Thisisanotherteststring` 


But the CR and LF were retained

Comment: @immzi: this is the reason why I suggested you to change your replacement string with `" "` instead of `""`

Comment: yeah, but that did not remove my big space between the words

Comment: @immzi: It does, copy/paste the example and try again.

Comment: Ohh yeah, my bad :( ...had missed out the + Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
String tmp = input.replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Comment: And a lot clearer than the other. And faster I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

```
String subject = "This is a      test string\r\nThis is another       test string";
String result = subject.replaceAll("(?=.*?[^\r\n])[\\s]{2,}", " ");;
```

Positive lookeahead than exclude `\r\n` - `(?=.*?[^\r\n])`
Matches and replaces 2 or more spaces with just 1.

**OUTPUTS:**

> This is a test string\r\nThis is another test string

**DEMO:**
http://ideone.com/9dOiBp